# Somar valores de uma tabela em php

Tags: php

Tenho uma tabela que retorna os meus pedidos do dia, ela esta funcionando perfeitamente, porém gostaria de acrescentar um "resumo" nela, com a somatória dos valores diários (quantidade de pedidos e valor total de pedidos).

A etapa que retorna os valores é:

```
<td>R$ <?=$pedido->valor_pedido;?></td>
```

Minha tabela:

```
<table class="table table-stripped table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr class="pedidos-dia">
                            <th width="50">Pedido</th>
                            <th>Cliente</th>
                            <th>Meio Pagamento</th>
                            <th>Valor Frete</th>
                            <th>Total Pedido</th>
                            <th>Situação</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <?php
                            if($pedido[0]->pagamento == "D") {
                                $valor_pedidos = $pedido[0]->valor_total_produtos - $pedido[0]->desconto;
                                $valor_final   = $valor_pedidos - ($valor_pedidos * 0.05) + $pedido[0]->frete;
                            } else {
                                $valor_final = $pedido[0]->valor_pedido;
                            }
                            ?>
                        <?php
                        if(count($pedidos) > 0){
                            foreach($pedidos as $pedido){
                                $totalHoje  += $valorCompra;
                        ?>
                        <tr onclick="window.location='<?=base_url();?>index.php/adm/pedidos/alterar/<?=$pedido->id;?>'" style="cursor:pointer" target='_blank'>

                            <td width="50"><?=$pedido->id;?></td>
                            <td class="pedidonome"><?=strtolower($pedido->nome ? $pedido->nome : $pedido->razao_social);?></td>
                            <td><?php echo getPagamento($pedido->pagamento);?></td>
                            <td>R$ <?=$pedido->frete;?></td>
                            <td>R$ <?=$pedido->valor_pedido;?></td>
                            <td><span class="<?=$pedido->situacao;?>"><?=$pedido->situacao;?></span></td>

                        </tr>
                        <?php 
                            }
                        } else {
                            ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2">Não há pedidos hoje.</td>
                            </tr>
                            <?php
                        }
                        ?>                            
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Crie uma variável para guardar essas informações fora do seu foreach, e para cada pedido percorrido, acrescente a quantidade, valor total, e qualquer outra coisa que precisar.

Seu código vai ficar mais ou menos assim:

```
<?php

$totalPedido = 0;

foreach ($pedidos as $pedido) {
    $totalPedido += $pedido->total_pedido;
}

//$totalPedido terá a somatória do atributo "total_pedido" a partir daqui...
```

Uma outra alternativa é utilizar [array_reduce](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-reduce.php):

```
<?php

$totalPedido = array_reduce($pedidos, function($total, $pedido) {
    return $total + $pedido->total_pedido;
});
```

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado!